# How to get a voltage range of -1.5V to 1.5V using batteries combination of 3V and potentiometer

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider, input, testing

How to get a voltage range of -1.5V to 1.5V using batteries combination of 3V and potentiometer.

So for the details, I'm using batteries of 1.5V each, which are connected in series such that output is of 3 Volts.

Now the postive and negative terminals of Battery are connected with terminals of potentiometer and the common terminal is connected to batteries common terminal as shown in picture attached.

Potentiometer is of 10K ohms.

The resistors used are of 10k and one terminal is shorted with each other + to the common terminal of potentiometer, the other ends are connected to positive and negative terminals of battery.

I want to get -1.5V to 1.5V varying supply for the input,for testing purpose.
[image: mentioned picture]

Comment: Please draw a circuit diagram of what you have. Note that you can label the connection between the batteries as 0 V ;)

Comment: Welcome ! Please can you draw a schematic of your problem, it will be helpful for us to help you :)

Comment: With 2 x 1.5V batteries in series you don't need a potentiometer or any other component to achieve an output of +1.5V and -1.5V. All you need are the batteries themselves.